# Get data in a specific time interval from Cassandra DB using Hector Api

Tags: cassandra, hector

I'm new to cassandra database. I'm using hector api to extract data from a **cassandra 1.2.11 DB** using `RangeSlicesQuery` and i'm successfully able to get from the database. The primary key of the table which i'm querying is in `LexicalUUID` and i can't change it to `time based UUIDs` as i'm not allowed to change the DB structure by my client. There is also a column which stores `time in epoch type Integer` in that table and I want to query the DB based on that time for a specific time interval. Can anyone guide me how I can do that using the **hector api** as the time column is not the table key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might have found the answer to my question. I have yet to test this but i think if I use  `IndexedSlicesQuery` instead of `RangeSlicesQuery` as it has special methods to add expressions for `equals, greater and less than`.etc. If anyone else faces the same problem then consult the following links for both documentation and some examples:

[Why use IndexedSlicesQuery instead of RangeSlicesQuery](http://www.bigdataplanet.info/2013/09/IndexedSliceQuery-is-Deprecated-with-Hector-1.2.html)

[IndexedSlicesQuery Documentation](http://hector-client.github.io/hector/source/content/API/core/0.8.0-2/me/prettyprint/cassandra/model/IndexedSlicesQuery.html)

[Examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.IndexedSlicesQuery)